# Push/Pull values on nested array mongoose

Tags: arrays, mongoose, nested

Im trying to update a value in a nested Array in a mongoose schema using express. I have the code required in place what i figuered i needed to update it, but the array doesn't get updated.

So the idea is to be able to have an *array of data base schema* objects with two fields, *schemaName* and *schemaFields*. I want to be able to update (add/remove)the values from *schemaFields* field of a specific *schema object* as needed.

I've already tried a bunch of stuff on here and elsewhere on the internet but nothing appears to work. I tried using findOneAndUpdate, findByIdAndUpdate etc.

My mongoose schema is as follows,

```
let databaseSchema = new Schema({
  schemaName: { type: String },
  schemaFields: [String]
});

let databaseSchemas = new Schema(
  {
    dbSchemas: [databaseSchema]
  },
  {
    collection: 'databaseSchemas'
  }
);
```

my update function is as follows,

```
schemasModel.mongo
    .update(
      {
        _id: req.body.documentId,
        'dbSchemas._id': req.body.schemaId 
      },
      console.log('preparin to push the field \n'),
      {
        $push: {
          'dbSchemas.$.schemaFields': req.body.newField
        }
      }
    )
    .then(() => {
      res.send('new field added successfully');
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I solved it by removing the console.log() as a second argument to the model.update() function. Apparently this has to be the object with the operation.

The working code for the Model.update function is as follows,

```
schemasModel.mongo
.update(
  {
    _id: req.body.documentId,
    'dbSchemas.schemaName': req.body.schemaToSearch
  },
  {
    $push: {
      'dbSchemas.$.schemaFields': req.body.newField
    }
  }
)
.then(() => {
  res.send('new field added successfully');
});
```